# The definition of sequences in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Can someone give a example for a sequence defined in Linear Algebra by Stephen H. Friedberg
Arnold J. Insel
Lawrence E. Spence?

The sequence $\sigma$  such that $\sigma(n) = a_n$ is denoted {$a_n$}.

Can't imagine what the form of this sequence looks like.

Comment: It is just a sequence whose $n$-th term is $a_n$ in the completely normal sense of that word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michal commented, this is the standard definition of sequence.

A sequence of elements in $F$ ($F$ doesn't even need to be a field for that, just any set), is a collection of elements $a_n \in F$. So for every positive integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you have an element $a_n \in F$.

So a sequence is the same thing as a function $a : \mathbb{N} \to F : n \mapsto a_n$.

So just pick your favorite sequence, and you can write it as a function like this.

---

(Now, I said that this didn't require $F$ to be a field, but a bit later when they define addition and multiplication by a scalar, that does require you to be working over a space where you can make sense of these notions).

Comment: A collection of elements an：{a1...an}did you mean?

Comment: Yes, but infinitely many. So $\{a_1,...,a_n,...\}, a_n \in F$

Comment: Okay, and $\sigma$ outputs $a_n$, if we want we can also say there is a function $\beta$ outputs $b_n$?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. And then, define the sum of your two sequences as the sum of these two functions :)